# ReferenceError: launchnavigator is not defined

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing and Android app under Cordova.

I've added successfully the plugin to the project with :

`cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator`

Note : the plugin `launchnavigator` is present under `/plugins`.

Then according to this tutorial : https://www.npmjs.com/package/uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator

I tried a simple navigation to London, UK, like this :

```
launchnavigator.navigate("London, UK");
```

But I get the following error :

```
"ReferenceError: launchnavigator is not defined
at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/6f9ead4e.scripts.js:4363:13
at j (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:12:19786)
at file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:12:20463
at k.$eval (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:12:25596)
at k.$digest (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:12:24168)
at k.$apply (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:12:25926)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:19:20693)
at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:2:29002)
at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js:2:25715)", source: file:///android_asset/www/scripts/ab53ae49.modules.js (12)
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Make sure you wait until the `deviceready` event is fired since Cordova plugins are loading dynamically at runtime:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    launchnavigator.navigate("London, UK");
}, false);
```

(2) Download the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/phonegap-launch-navigator-example) which contains several Cordova projects which can be used as a working reference.

Comment: Looks like nothing happened, as if deviceready is indeed never fired. I'm looking into examples right now to see if I do the necessary for it to launch.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling / reinstalling all plugins and it all worked out. Thanks for helping me narrowing down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the version of the uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator plugin is compatible with your version of Cordova.

I was having this issue due to having a Cordova version which was too old for the plugin. Preferably update Cordova if possible, or else downgrade the plugin to an older but compatible version.